# 403 forbidden when Django folder is located in /root

Tags: django, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to deploy my local Django site on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I followed a tutorial, and everything seems to work fine, except Apache won't allow me to store my Django project under `/root`. More specifically, I get a 403 Forbidden when trying to access my site.

I suspect I need to configure my virtual host in a different manner. Any ideas?

Here is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/me/index.wsgi

        Alias /static/ /root/me/static/
    <Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/mysite/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Define `DocumentRoot` e.g. `DocumentRoot /root/me/my_project`

Comment: Have you checked directory permissions/owners ?

Comment: It does not answer your question, but if you want to make your conf easier, take a look to: https://bitnami.com/stack/django

Comment: Why would you want to put your Django project there? `/root` is basically the home directory for the "root" user, not somewhere you store data or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I'll mark this as the correct answer for future reference.

I ended up moving the whole Django project to `/home/anotheruser`, and defined `DocumentRoot` as per Aamir Adnans suggestion. After `service apache2 restart` it started working.